# How to observe array's new values with combine?

Tags: swift, combine

If I have an array:

```swift
var arr = [0,1,2]
```

And a Combine publisher for it:

```swift
arr.publisher
    .sink { completion in print("Completed with \(completion)")
    } receiveValue: { val in
        print("Received value \(val)")
    }
arr.append(3)
```

Why does it finish right away with:

```swift
Received value 0
Received value 1
Received value 2
Completed with finished
```

How can I make Combine execute the code every time I append values to the array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `publisher` method of the array does exactly that - emits every element of the array and then completes, because the array at the time of calling the publisher has a finite number of elements.

If you want to be notified every time the arrays changes (not just when something is appended to it, but on any change) then create a `@Published var` for the array and attach the observer to it:

```
@Published var arr = [1,2,3]

cancellable = $arr
    .sink { completion in print("Completed with \(completion)")
    } receiveValue: { val in
        print("Received value \(val)")
    }

arr.append(4)
```

The output will be:

```
Received value [1, 2, 3]
Received value [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But looks like what you are really looking for is listening to a stream of numbers emitted one at a time. Then define a `@Published var` of that type and listen to it. You'll get called every time the var changes:

```
@Published var value = 1

cancellable = $value
    .sink { completion in print("Completed with \(completion)")
    } receiveValue: { val in
        print("Received value \(val)")
    }

value = 2
value = 3
value = 4
```

The output will be:

```
Received value 1
Received value 2
Received value 3
Received value 4
```

Comment: What if I want to subscribe to an array defined in UIKit, for example, UIStackView's arrangedSubviews array. I want it to publish each time the array elements change. I tried doing this with `publisher(for: \.arrangedSubviews)` on the stack view, but it's not working. Let me know if you want this as a separate question in Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can only use that kind of publisher on key-value observable properties (KVO). `arrangedSubviews` is not a KVO property.

Comment: Is there an easy way to identify if a property is KVO or not? Instead of manually trying it on a publisher and observing the effect?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy way to tell in general. Sometimes Apple documentation states that a given property is KVO observable but it fails to say so for many that in fact are KVO observable. 
For one thing if a property is `readonly` (only has a getter) then it's almost certainly is not KVO observable, and the `arrangedSubviews` is a readonly property.